# Cloudflare on localhost using docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, cloudflare

I am pretty new to tunneling and cloudflare in particular. I am having a difficult time exposing Jenkins, running on `localhost:8080` using cloudflare so I can create a webhook for github. So I created a tunnel using cloudflare, which is running in a docker container.

To create the tunnel I had to use [cloudflare zero trust dashboard](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/tunnel-guide/remote/#set-up-a-tunnel-remotely-dashboard-setup), where by I mentioned that my localhost url should be exposed through the tunnel. For some reason, whenever I try to access the public hostname that I created using the browser I get `error 502 bad gateway`. However, whenever I try to tunnel any other public url that is not localhost I am directed to the correct site.

These are the container logs every time I try to access the public host name

```
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Starting tunnel tunnelID=22f5be5d-f85d-436e-9bc6-a7e5dc4e4f35
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Cannot determine default configuration path. No file [config.yml config.yaml] in [~/.cloudflared ~/.cloudflare-warp ~/cloudflare-warp /etc/cloudflared /usr/local/etc/cloudflared]
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Version 2022.7.1
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF GOOS: linux, GOVersion: go1.17.1, GoArch: amd64
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Settings: map[no-autoupdate:true token:*****]
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Generated Connector ID: f9147c6d-a615-4286-aefe-ab3498ee1205
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Will be fetching remotely managed configuration from Cloudflare API. Defaulting to protocol: quic
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Initial protocol quic
2022-08-10T17:00:47Z INF Starting metrics server on 127.0.0.1:40785/metrics
2022-08-10T17:00:49Z INF Connection 5a87c9da-628c-4d13-8260-cc87e90c9ded registered connIndex=0 ip=198.41.200.63 location=JNB
2022-08-10T17:00:49Z INF Updated to new configuration config="{\"ingress\":[{\"hostname\":\"jenkins_webhook.piii314.tk\",\"originRequest\":{\"httpHostHeader\":\"\"},\"service\":\"https://localhost:8080\"},{\"service\":\"http_status:404\"}],\"warp-routing\":{\"enabled\":false}}" version=13
2022-08-10T17:00:50Z INF Connection 3d648068-fc89-4ff2-a135-bb55998ce6f5 registered connIndex=2 ip=198.41.200.193 location=JNB
2022-08-10T17:00:51Z INF Connection ef523b57-6908-4c03-bce5-a27af7a3fac8 registered connIndex=1 ip=198.41.192.167 location=CPT
2022-08-10T17:00:52Z INF Connection 702a4312-27f2-4d05-8434-f2061d97e98f registered connIndex=3 ip=198.41.192.7 location=CPT
2022-08-10T17:01:36Z INF Updated to new configuration config="{\"ingress\":[{\"service\":\"http://localhost:8080\",\"hostname\":\"jenkins_webhook.piii314.tk\",\"originRequest\":{\"httpHostHeader\":\"\"}},{\"service\":\"http_status:404\"}],\"warp-routing\":{\"enabled\":false}}" version=14
2022-08-10T17:04:19Z ERR  error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" cfRay=738a4f594ddf9e94-JNB ingressRule=0 originService=http://localhost:8080
2022-08-10T17:04:19Z ERR Request failed error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" connIndex=0 dest=https://jenkins_webhook.piii314.tk/ ip=198.41.200.63 type=http
2022-08-10T17:04:20Z ERR  error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" cfRay=738a4f60097d9e94-JNB ingressRule=0 originService=http://localhost:8080
2022-08-10T17:04:20Z ERR Request failed error="Unable to reach the origin service. The service may be down or it may not be responding to traffic from cloudflared: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" connIndex=0 dest=https://jenkins_webhook.piii314.tk/favicon.ico ip=198.41.200.63 type=http
```

Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I have no understanding of the "why" but from trial and error the solution I came to is to use the container IP instead of localhost

so it would be like `172.17.0.#:8080` from your `localhost:8080`

hope that helps

Comment: But, do I really need to mention the container's IP since my local port maps the containers port?

Comment: For me its because of the way I have set my UFW rules. But, yes, I did not come to a way to just use `localhost:port`. I just ended up making a new bridge network and setting static IPs for all my containers. 
Also I was running into an issue where my docker net was only IPv4 and so IPv6 devices were not able to connect to the service via the tunnel.

Comment: Confirm, this method worked!